# How to add extra field in model serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am very new to django rest framework. I have two models ModelA and ModelB.

I have a ModelB searilzer to display all the fields in get request.

Because of some reasons `ModelA and ModelB` are not related by `FK` but `ModelA.objects.get(modelB.field1=modelA.pk)` this will return single data.

```
class ModelASerailzer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ['f1','f2']


class ModelBSerailzer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      # I want to do something like this here
         extra_field = ModelA.objects.get(modelB.field1=modelA.pk).f1 # this will return the data in shell 
                 #and normal django view but I don't know how to implement this in django rest ?
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = ['field1','field2', 'extra_field']
```

I tried like this

```
class ModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    extra_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_extra_field(self, member):
        return ModelA.objects.get(pk=member.field).f1
    class Meta:
      model = ModelB
      fields = ['field1','field2', 'extra_field']
```

With this I got this error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`

**`ModelA.objects.get(pk=member.field).f1` is a FileField.**