# How to exclude fields from nested representation Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have following UserSerializer class

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['id', 'persons']
    depth = 1
```

The depth option allows me generate nested representations

```
{
"id": 2,
"persons": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Alex",
        "city": "Paris",
        "bio": "This is my bio",
        "phone_number": "9130095484",
        "age": 24,
        "height": 56,
        "weight": 54}
]
```

I don't need all fields in nested representation. How to exclude some fields but keep the depth option?

The PersonSerializer looks like this

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

comments = CommentSerializer(source='comment_set', many=True)
images = ImageSerializer(source='image_set', many=True)

class Meta:
    model = Person
    exclude = ('paid', 'register_date', 'purchase_date')
```

Comment: You need to create a serializer for the model that `persons` links to and include/exclude the fields you want there

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `PersonSerializer` with required fields and use it inside `UserSerializer`.

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # required fields here


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    persons = PersonSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'persons']
        depth = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited the question

Comment: Well, if you want to exclude some fields from `CommentSerializer` or `ImageSerializer`, it will be the same thing.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add related models ( by foreign key) to PersonSerializer?

Comment: How about that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64629500/how-to-add-extra-field-in-model-serializer/64630669#64630669